# List http response code - Compatible with Python2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I want to get a list of response codes (Not to harcode it) from a library.

In python2 I could easily do something like this:

```
import httplib
....
if res.status_code != httplib.OK:
     do_something
```

`httplib` is not present in python3 (I think I `hhtp.client` is in python3?)

Is there a library compatible with **both** Python2 and 3 to read the avaialble status codes?

Comment: I have to ask, what is this *for*?

Comment: Have you considered [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Comment: `six.moves.http_client.OK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to use `requests`.

```
import requests

some_request = requests.get('some link')
some_request.raise_for_status()
# Rest of the code
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes), an error will only be raised if a request is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
   import httplib as client
except:
   from http import client

#do some stuff here
```